Shading of blocks does not work properly with beamer and pgfpagesuselayout through latex + dvipdfmx
I am using Beamer with latex + dvipdfmx since I would like to use Beamer with Japanese and (up)latex + dvipdfmx is better than pdflatex for Japanese. Also, I tried to make handouts out of the Beamer slides with 2 slides on 1 page.  To this end, I found \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1} from the pgf(more)pages package.
Based on the above requirements with one additional requirement

use latex + dvipdfmx as the typeset engine,
put 2 slides on 1 page using \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1},
use the Boadilla beamer theme,

my MWE is
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default] %Of course, this works properly.
%\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false] %This is still OK.
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] %This gives incorrect shading.

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{problem}
To shade, or not to shade.
\end{problem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

However, this gives a block with broken shadow as follows.


Q. How one can fix this broken shading?

It's also helpful to get an alternative to \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}, but I would like to keep latex + dvipdfmx and blocks with shadows. Probably, one solution can be a use of pdfxup after making slides without \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1} but I would like to get a solution without modifying anything besides the LaTeX source itself.
Some additional information:

As the above MWE includes, blocks with the default theme works properly.
Blocks with rounded theme but without shading works properly as well.
Indeed, I obtained such broken shadows when I tried to print the pdf file (without using \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}) of slides  with the "2 on 1" layout. (I also would like to get a possible explanation for this in an accessible manner for beginners like me.)


Would an unicode-aware engine like lualatex be a suitable alternative to (up)latex + dvipdfmx?

Well, yeah that's probably the "proper" solution of the "new generation". But I am rather a bit old school... (I guess lualatex need some extra packages to deal with Japanese properly though.)

If the shading between the title and the body isn't crucial, you could use the tcolorbox inner beamer theme to get blocks with shadows:
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default] %Of course, this works properly.
%\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false] %This is still OK.
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] %This gives incorrect shading.

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{problem}
To shade, or not to shade.
\end{problem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Wow, nice and easy solution! Thx! Indeed, I rather like not having shading between the title and contents of block and I choose yours as the best answer. However, I also expecting someone give a simple solution with keeping the shading between title and contents, just as an extra interest.
